# Do I need to install Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable if my Windows already has Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable?

Tags: windows, windows-10, visual-studio-2012, visual-c++, redistributable

I am using `Windows 10`. I am trying to install 1 open source software.

In the `readme.txt` of that software, it says it requires `Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable`. I found that my Windows already has `Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable` installed.

After I install the open source software, it seems that it is working, even though I haven't installed `Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable`.

Do I need to install `Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable` if my Windows already has `Visual Studio 2012 Redistributable`?

Comment: You need it if you have software that requires 2008 and not 2010.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may or may not, depending on the software that requires the redistributable. Some software is written to rely on a specific redistributable, while another software may be written to rely on that older redistributable but is also able to use any of the more recent versions all the way up to the latest version.

From [microsoft's forum:](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/multiple-visual-c-redistributables-needed/e533cd40-8712-4803-8a31-316c83a5bc88?auth=1)

> Visual C++ redistributables do not supersede each other. Some apps may
>   be very specific to bind to the exact version of the Visual C++ dlls,
>   for example, to make sure the app runs exactly as published. Most
>   apps, however, bind to the latest edition of the same major version,
>   as it is the default behavior and can benefit from Microsoft's
>   security updates.
>
> There could be multiple versions of Visual C++ redistributables
>   required by one app. For example, if an app depending on Visual C++
>   2008 redistributable uses a component depending on Visual C++ 2005
>   redistributable, the app's developer must ship both versions of Visual
>   C++  redistributables.

When in doubt, it's probably a good idea to install the additional one that it says it requires, even though it may not be absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to install every distribute. You just install Netframework 3.5(contain 3.0 2.0 1.0) for older software to use it. Nowdays, we use Netframework 4.0 and higher latest 4.6.

Visual C++ XXXX Redistributable is Netframework. Inside Netframework contain Visual C++ Redistributable. Just install ONLY when your software NEEDED. Dont install things that not related. Save space and make it simple.

Solution: Just install Netframework 3.5 
Link: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21